# Get child and sub child nodes in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, parsing, output

I have a grid made in html like so

```
<div class="grid-container" id="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-row">
                <div class="grid-cell red"><p class="label">R</p></div>
                <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                <div class="grid-cell blue"><p class="label">B</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-row">
                <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                <div class="grid-cell white"><p class="label">W</p></div>
                <div class="grid-cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-row">
                <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                <div class="grid-cell blue"><p class="label">B</p></div>
                <div class="grid-cell blue"><p class="label">B</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to be able to make JavaScript updates to each cell individually. For this I tried to write a script that gets all the child nodes of the grid and then again get the child nodes of each row. However when I test the output the three rows return fine but the children of them return as 7 objects instead of 3. I'm very confused...

```
function myFunction() {
var c = document.getElementById("grid-container").childNodes;
var b;
var txt = "";
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    txt = txt + "Row: " + c[i].nodeName + "<br>";
    b = c[i].childNodes;
    for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        txt = txt + "Cell: " + b[i].nodeName + " Value: " + b[i].className + "<br>";
    }

}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;}
```

Here is the output it gives me:

[image: Output]

Comment: The #text nodes represent the whitespace between the tags. Try `children` instead of `childNodes` to only consider actual HTML tags.

Comment: @Loilo wow thanks!!! That worked great, my only question now is: it still shows all the sub child’s as the same class when they should be three different ones?

Comment: Because you accidentally accessed `b[i]` where you probably wanted to access `b[j]`. ;)

Comment: @Loilo ... well that’s twice I’ve done that haha, once again thank you very much

Comment: My pleasure. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of writing an answer credit to Loilo, simply use `children` instead of `childNodes`